# Merging 2 very large text files, update each line, without using memory

Tags: php, python, memory, file-io, merge

Say I've got 2 text files with around 2 million lines each (~50-80MB file size each). The structure of both files is the same:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
...
```

**Column 1** never changes, **Column 2**: the same value may not be in both files, and won't be in the same order for both files, **Column3** is a number and will be different in every file.

I need to be able to merge them both into one file, matched by Column 2. If Column2 exists in both files, update Column3 by adding the values of Column3 from both files together.

If the files weren't so huge, I could easily do this in PHP by reading each line of both files into arrays and going from there, but doing so easily overloads the memory available.

Is there a way to do this with without loading each line into memory? I'm mostly familiar with PHP, but open to Python, Java or Shell scripts if they are not too complicated to understand.

Comment: What's the problem with loading 50mb into memory?

Comment: You have to read each line to check Column2 right? In that case, each line will have to be placed into memory at some point. Also is this something that must be done often or is it just a once in a blue moon task?

Comment: ever thought about using a database?

Comment: @agf I'm with you on this.  Especially since there's only two basic ways to do this(that I can think of) - line-by-line read and update (given the use case, n^2), or read one file worth of `Column2` and `Column3` into memory (in Java, probably a `HashMap`) and update from a single read of the second file.  I guess maybe you could 'batch' the records (read a set into memory, update from other file, put back in original, delete used records, repeat).

Comment: @agf Loading each file's contents into memory using PHP arrays eats up the allocated memory almost right away. The memory_limit for php on my server is 90M, so I'm not sure... Is memory usage calculated differently than physical file size?

Comment: @webbiedave yes, I am aware of some memory usage being needed. Line by line can be easily controlled and cleared. This process would be run daily, and be done to 24 files at a time (1 for each hour of the day)

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with command line `sort(1)`to merge and sort the files . After that, it should be a simple script to compute the sums. I don't know PHP, so I'll give my example in python:

```
sort -k2 <file1> <file2> | python -c "
  import itertools,sys
  allLines = (x.strip().split(' ') for x in sys.stdin)
  groups = itertools.groupby(allLines, lambda x:x[1])
  for k,lines in groups:
      firstLine = iter(g).next()
      print firstLine[0], firstline[1], sum(int(x[2]) for x in lines)
"
```

Comment: Auugh!  8 seconds ahead of me.  Un-freaking-believable.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so if I'm reading this right, you'll have:

file1:

```
abc 12 34
abc 56 78
abc 90 12
```

file2:

```
abc 90 87  <-- common column 2
abc 12 67  <---common column 2
abc 23 1   <-- unique column 2
```

output should be:

```
abc 12 101
abc 90 99
```

If that's the case, then something like this (assuming they're .csv-formatted):

```
$f1 = fopen('file1.txt', 'rb');
$f2 = fopen('file2.txt', 'rb');
$fout = fopen('outputxt.');

$data = array();
while(1) {
    if (feof($line1) || feof($line2)) {
        break; // quit if we hit the end of either file
    }

    $line1 = fgetcsv($f1);
    if (isset($data[$line1[1]])) {
       // saw the col2 value earlier, so do the math for the output file:
       $col3 = $line1[2] + $data[$line1[1]];
       $output = array($line[0], $line1[1], $col3);
       fputcsv($fout, $output);
       unset($data[$line1[1]]);
    } else {
       $data[$line1[1]] = $line1; // cache the line, if the col2 value wasn't seen already
    }

    $line2 = fgetcsv($f2);
    if (isset($data[$line2[1]])) {
       $col3 = $data[$line2[1]] + $line2[2];
       $newdata = array($line2[0], $line2[1], $col3);
       fputcsv($fout, $newdata);
       unset($data[$line2[1]]); // remove line from cache
    } else {
       $data[$line2[1]] = $line2;
    }
}

fclose($f1);
fclose($f2);
fclose($fout);
```

This is going off the top of my head, not tested, probably won't work, YMMV, etc...

It'd simplify things immensely if you pre-sort the two input files, so that column2 is used as the sort key. That'd keep the cache size down, as you'd know if you'd seen a matched value already and when to dump the earlier cached data.

Comment: Yep, you're reading it mostly correct. Column2 is a string and is already sorted. The only missing thing is I still want to write the line if Column2 is not matched in both files.

While it might be exhausting due to the number of total lines, looking for a match in the second file and then writing both to a new file is probably the best.

Comment: do an `fputcsv($data)` after the loop, to dump out the cache array. Hopefully not too many values in the two files would be unique, otherwise you'll end having most of both files in ram anyways.

Comment: `fgetcsv()` and `fputcsv()` are causing an error - I added `fgetcsv($f1, 1000, " ");` since the columns are separated by a space. returns the error `Message:  fgetcsv(): delimiter must be a character`. Is there anything more I need to do to format as csv?

Answer (score 1):

What may throwing you is that you are looking at two files.  There's no need for that.  To use Mark's excellent example:
file1:

```
abc 12 34
abc 56 78
abc 90 12
```

file2:

```
abc 90 87  
abc 12 67  
abc 23 1
```

then

```
sort file1 file2 > file3
```

yields
file3:

```
abc 12 34
abc 12 67  
abc 23 1
abc 56 78
abc 90 12
abc 90 87
```

Second week of CS-101 to reduce that down to its final form.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it easily with Python sqlite3 included module without using much memory (around 13 Mb with 1 million rows):

```
import sqlite3

files = ("f1.txt", "f2.txt")    # Files to compare

# # Create test data
# for file_ in files:
#   f = open(file_, "w")
#   fld2 = 0
#   for fld1 in "abc def ghi jkl".split():
#       for fld3 in range(1000000 / 4):
#           fld2 += 1
#           f.write("%s %s %s\n" % (fld1, fld2, 1))
# 
#   f.close()

sqlite_file = "./join.tmp"      # or :memory: if you don't want to create a file

cnx = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)

for file_ in range(len(files)):     # Create & load tables
    table = "file%d" % (file_+1)
    cnx.execute("drop table if exists %s" % table)
    cnx.execute("create table %s (fld1 text, fld2 int primary key, fld3 int)" % table)

    for line in open(files[file_], "r"):
        cnx.execute("insert into %s values (?,?,?)" % table, line.split())

# Join & result
cur = cnx.execute("select f1.fld1, f1.fld2, (f1.fld3+f2.fld3) from file1 f1 join file2 f2 on f1.fld2==f2.fld2")
while True:
    row = cur.fetchone()
    if not row:
        break

    print row[0], row[1], row[2]

cnx.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP's memory_limit is appropriate for its primary intended task of web server scripting. It is wildly inappropriate for batch processing data, like the job you're trying to do. The problem is PHP's configured memory_limit, not that you're trying to do something that needs "too much" memory. My *phone* has easily enough memory to just load 2 80Mb files into memory and do this the fast/easy way, let alone any sort of real computer which should be able to load gigabytes (or at least 1 GB) of data without breaking a sweat.

Apparently you can set PHP's memory_limit (which is arbitrary and very small by today's standards) at runtime with `ini_set`, just for this script. Do you know how much memory you actually have available on the server? I know a lot of shared hosting providers do give you very small amounts of memory by today's standards, because they don't expect you to be doing much more than processing web page requests. But you probably can just do this directly in PHP the way you want to, without jumping through hoops (and massively slowing down the process) to try to avoid loading all of the files into memory at once.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried setting the memory at run time with `init_set`, doing a quick `phpinfo()` shows that it has updated, however when the script is run, the error message implies that even less memory was allocated. Perhaps the server is blocking the `init_set` capability for memory_limit? I'm on a virtual private server, which gives me a little more control than a basic shared server.

Comment: Can you find out the actual amount of RAM the VPS provider is giving you? If *that*'s too low, then you'll have no choice but to look at memory-saving solutions, no matter what you use. What limit did you try increasing it to?

Comment: I believe it is 300MB - and it is scalable. Without running the `ini_set` function, it allocates 94371840 bytes - 90mb default. I tried increasing to 200MB and my shell connection was terminated.